# Controlling DataTrigger ExitActions

Tags: wpf, storyboard, datatrigger

I have a CheckBox (placed above an image) whose Opacity is set to 0 by default. When IsMouseOver is true, the CheckBox Opacity property is animated from 0 to 1 and reversed when IsMouseOver is false. However, if the CheckBox IsSelected is true, then the reverse animation(i.e DataTrigger.ExitActions) should not execute. i.e CheckBox should remain visible if it is checked. In my XAML the checkbox is disappearing even when it is checked.

Following is my XAML:

```
<CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <CheckBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=imageGrid, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard Timeline.DesiredFrameRate="100">
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="00:00:00.400" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard Timeline.DesiredFrameRate="100">
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="0" Duration="00:00:00.400" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </CheckBox.Style>
    </CheckBox>
```

Implemented the way @feO2x suggested. However it is not working as expected. Got it work in a simple application. However I intend to use the checkbox in a ListViewItem. Following is my XAML:

```
<Style x:Key="ThumbView_ItemContainerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="175" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="125" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Grid Background="Pink" x:Name="mygrid">
                    <Rectangle Name="LBRect" Fill="Transparent" Opacity="0.195" />
                    <Image Name="posterImg" Margin="0,0,0,0" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="{Binding Path=ProfilePic}" Height="125" MaxWidth="125" />
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" x:Name="CheckBox">
                        <CheckBox.RenderTransform>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.1" ScaleY="1.1" />
                        </CheckBox.RenderTransform>

                        <CheckBox.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ThumbViewCheckBoxStyle}">
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0" />
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                            <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}}" Value="False" />
                                            <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=CheckBox, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False" />
                                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:0.4" />
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                        <MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0.4" />
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </CheckBox.Style>
                    </CheckBox>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Hey Lucifer, I updated my answer to reflect your concerns with the `CheckBox` style within the `ListView` control template. Sorry that it took so long but I have been busy the last few days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with [IMultiValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in place. Pass two bindings to it i.e. `IsMouseOver` and `IsChecked`.

**Converter**:

```
public class MyConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                          CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool isMouseOver = (bool)values[0];
        bool isChecked = (bool)values[1];

        return isChecked || isMouseOver;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes,
                                object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**XAML**:

```
<DataTrigger Value="True">
   <DataTrigger.Binding>
      <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyConverter}">
         <Binding Path="IsMouseOver" ElementName="imageGrid"/>
         <Binding Path="IsChecked" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
      </MultiBinding>
   </DataTrigger.Binding>
   <!-- Rest same trigger -->
</DataTrigger>
```

Of course you need to add `MyValueConverter` instance as resource in your XAML file.

Comment: Hi @Rohit Vats, could you shed some light as to why the DataTrigger implementation is not working as expected. I implemented feO2x suggestion. Have edited my question to include the new xaml implementation.

Comment: I accept the answer. Although I wanted a XAML only solution without a converter. @Rohit Vats

Comment: What about my solution which actually is XAML only?

Answer (score 0):

**Update February 26th:** In your Style that is not working, you reference the checkbox the wrong way. `ElementName` can only be used in a binding if the target control was given a name and is accessible within the current WPF XAML namescope (you can learn about XAML namescopes [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746659%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

You should use a relative source within your binding to reference the CheckBox correctly: `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}`. The following `ListView` style shows the whole example:

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" Grid.Column="1">
                            <CheckBox.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.0" />
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}"
                                                        Value="False" />
                                                <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                                        Value="False" />
                                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                            <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                                        To="0.0" Duration="0:0:0.4" />
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </BeginStoryboard>
                                            </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                            <MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                                        To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0.4" />
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </BeginStoryboard>
                                            </MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </CheckBox.Style>
                        </CheckBox>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

You can download a working example from [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14810011/AnimatedCheckBoxInListView.zip) (DropBox link).

**Original Answer:**
You can use a `MultiDataTrigger` within your style to accomplish the behavior you want. Have a look at the following code:

```
<CheckBox Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Check Me" Name="CheckBox">
    <CheckBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.0" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=Rectangle, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="False" />
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=CheckBox, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                 To="0.0"
                                                 Duration="0:0:0.4"
                                                 BeginTime="0:0:0.5" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                 To="1.0"
                                                 Duration="0:0:0.4" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </CheckBox.Style>
</CheckBox>
```

A `MultiDataTrigger` is used to describe two conditions that have to be true for the enter actions to be executed. In this case I choose that the `IsMouseOver` property of a rectangle as well as the `IsChecked` property of the checkbox must both be false. Thus the checkbox is faded in when the mouse is over the rectangle and stays visible when it becomes checked.

You can download my full sample [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14810011/CheckboxVisibility.zip) (it's a Dropbox link).

Hope this helps you. If you have any questions, please feel free to leave a comment.

Comment: I got your suggestion working in a simple appln. However, when I used it in my appln, where the checkbox is placed inside a ListViewItem, it does not work as expected. Please have a look at the new XAML posted.